# Load models to model test case in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, testing

Is there a good way to load many models to a model test case in CakePHP?

I've tried this way

```
class FooTestCase extends CakeTestCase {

public function setUp() {
    parent::setUp();

    $this->Foo = ClassRegistry::init('Foo');
    $this->Bar = ClassRegistry::init('Bar');
    $this->Unit = ClassRegistry::init('Unit');

}
}
```

Comment: That way is fine, although you should try and have one test case per model.

Comment: also make sure you got the fixtures for those models.

Comment: I might load a model only in a function

    public function testFoo() {
        $Foo = ClassRegistry::init('Foo');
    }